# ZXING port fails to decode qrcode

Tags: vb.net, zxing

I'm using the zxing C# port to decode a QR barcode.
The code is simple and based on an example I found online (see below).
The problem is, it always throws an "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception.
My code sample happen to be in VB.NET, but the zxing library is implemented in C#

```
Dim re As qrcode.QRCodeReader
re = New qrcode.QRCodeReader()

Dim Img As New Bitmap("<image file path here>")

Dim res As com.google.zxing.Result

Dim bufimg As com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageMonochromeBitmapSource
bufimg = New client.j2se.BufferedImageMonochromeBitmapSource(Img, False)
res = re.decode(bufimg)

Dim ret As String = res.getText()
```

I have seen multiple people complaining about the same issue in different forums, but haven't found any suggested solution.

**UPDATE** If anyone knows of a different good QR reader that can easily integrate with a .NET application, please recommend

Comment: You say C# twice, but I see VB code.  You should tag your question according to the code you are writing, not the library you happen to be using.

Comment: @Inuyasha the main issue is the C# zxing library. These are the keywords that should trigger the response (and people finding this sin search). I updated the question to try to make this clear.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the library was written in.  What is important is the code *you* are writing.

Comment: Has anyone made any progress in this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if this gonna help u, but i paste my code if u want to use:

```
Imports Zxing = com.google.zxing
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Decodificador
    'Para leer todo tipo de codigos soportados por el proyecto zxing
    Private Reader As New Zxing.MultiFormatReader
    'Private Reader As New Zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader
    Private Result As Zxing.Result
    Private Imagen As Bitmap
    Private Bitm As Zxing.BinaryBitmap
    Private HBin As Zxing.common.HybridBinarizer
    Private Lumin As RGBLuminanceSource
    'El orden para poder funcionar es: 
    'DetectarCodigoEnImagen (Obligatorio) >> PintarLocalizacion [opcional] >> DecodificarImagen (Obligatorio para sacar info).
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Devuelve True si ha localizado un QRCODE
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="img"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function DetectarCodigoEnImagen(ByRef img As Image) As Boolean
        Try
            Imagen = New Bitmap(img)
            'Creamos un Mapa binario con la imagen y su tamaño
            Lumin = New RGBLuminanceSource(Imagen, Imagen.Width, Imagen.Height)
            HBin = New Zxing.common.HybridBinarizer(Lumin)
            Bitm = New Zxing.BinaryBitmap(HBin)
            'Decodificamos el mapa binario y guardamos todos los datos en Result
            Result = Reader.decode(Bitm)
            'Si ha encontrado un QRCode provocará una excepción y devolverá False
            'Si hay un QRCode, devolverá True
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Dibuja cuadros rojos y amarillos en la localización del Codigo QR, ralentiza mucho el sistema.
    ''' Debe haberse detectado un codigo en la imagen para poder pintar.
    ''' Devuelve la imagen con el Codigo QR y la localización pintada
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="img"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function PintarLocalizacionQrCode(ByRef img As Image) As Image
        Try
            'Archivamos en una matriz todos los puntos de localización del QRcode
            Dim Puntos() As Zxing.ResultPoint = Result.ResultPoints
            'Creamos Graficos desde la imagen y poder pintar posteriormente
            Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Imagen)
            'Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Imagen)
            'Declaramos el tamaño del pincel para pintar y pintar2
            Dim TamPincel As Integer = 4
            Dim Pintar As New Pen(Color.Yellow, TamPincel)
            Dim Pintar2 As New Pen(Color.Red, TamPincel)
            'Declaramos una variable del mismo tipo que el arreglo Puntos() para poder navera por ella
            Dim PuntoAuxiliar As com.google.zxing.ResultPoint

            'Por cada punto en puntos() dibujamos 2 rectangulos en los indicadores de posición del QRCode
            For Each PuntoAuxiliar In Puntos
                gr.DrawRectangle(Pintar, New Rectangle(PuntoAuxiliar.X - 10, PuntoAuxiliar.Y - 10, 20, 20))
                gr.DrawRectangle(Pintar2, New Rectangle(PuntoAuxiliar.X - 13, PuntoAuxiliar.Y - 13, 26, 26))
            Next
            'Liberamos la memoria
            gr.Dispose()
            Return Imagen
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```